# C++ Passing in Vector by Reference but changes still not being saved

Tags: c++, vector

I made a project with a class called Card which has a name, suit, and value.

I have a deck class which makes a vector of  which has 52 elements.

I have a table class which handles many vectors: discard pile, players hand, etc.

Then just my main cpp which runs it all.

**Deck.h**

```
public:    
Deck();
void deal(vector<Card>& pile); //Deals a card from the top 
//of the deck to any passed-in hand or pile. 

private:
vector<Card> deck;
```

**Deck.cpp**

```
void Deck::deal(vector<Card>& pile) //Deal a card to whichever pile on the table.
{
    pile.push_back(deck[deck.size() - 1]); //Add the card from the deck to the pile
    deck.pop_back(); //Remove the card that we copied from      
}
```

**Table.h**

```
public:    
Table();
void deal(vector<Card>& pile); //Deals a card from the top 
//of the deck to any passed-in hand or pile. 
vector<Card> getPlayersCards();

private:
vector<Card> playersCards;
vector<Card> discard;
```

**Table.cpp**

```
vector<Card> Table::getPlayersCards()
{
    return playersCards;
}

vector<Card> Table::getDiscardPile()
{
    return discard;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
//VARIABLES
Deck theDeck;
Table theTable;

int main()
{
    theDeck.deal(theTable.getPlayersCards()); //Attempt to deal a card
    //out to the player's hand
}
```

so here's the problem, I put some couts in the program and here's what is happening. Notice how it works perfectly once it's in the deal method but as soon as it goes back to my main cpp, it forgets all about ever having moved that card. However the main deck has 51 cards, meaning THAT worked, which makes sense because the variable deck was not passed in.

[image]

If you guys can offer any help, I would be so appreciative.

Comment: Probably has something to do with `getPlayersCards()`/`getDiscardPile()` returning `vector`s by value, but it's hard to say for sure without a complete example. Your code is not even valid because you're binding an rvalue to a non-const reference. I'm guessing you compile using VisualStudio? Turn up the warning level.

Comment: `theTable.getPlayersCards()` is a temporary, so `theDeck.deal(theTable.getPlayersCards())` shouldn't even compile...

Comment: You can write `deck.back()` instead of `deck[deck.size() - 1]`. You should make sure `deck.empty()` is false before doing that.

Comment: @Praetorian I do use visual studio, but what do you mean by rvalue to a non constant reference? Also what do you mean by warning level?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `theTable.getPlayersCards()` is returning a copy of `vector<Card> playersCards` instead of a reference to it.

Try changing this in `Table.cpp`:

```
vector<Card>& Table::getPlayersCards()
{
  return playersCards;
}

vector<Card>& Table::getDiscardPile()
{
  return discard;
}
```

and this in `Table.h`:

```
vector<Card>& getPlayersCards();
vector<Card>& getDiscardPile();
```

Comment: That did it. Works perfectly now. Thank you guys so much. I had no idea return values worked like that.

Comment: @Hatefiend You should ask your instructor why he hasn't explained this basic concept to you.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm still extremely early on in my college classes. I've only completed two so far. The most recent class was 'introduction to C' and we stopped at 'pointers'. I know the answer is going to be 'read a textbook' but honestly I searched and searched on google and couldn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

The result from `getPlayersCards()` is a copy of the cards. Not a reference. So when `deal` returns the copy of its argument gets destroyed.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Had no idea.